# gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

my grid view contains a column having a text box. when i post back the page, i have to select all the rows where the value of each row's text box is > 0.
how can i do it ?

Comment: can you specify which event? a button click outside gridview or any of gridview events? can you paste some code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)   {
    // Selects the text from the TextBox
    // which is inside the GridView control

    string textBoxText = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
    // do waht ever
}
```

Comment: @rauf: please look at the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ.

```
var selectedRows = GridView1.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where(r=>((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox")).Text=="val")
```

and then foreach over the selected rows